# Introduce delete/undelete queues for qualified users

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get some more review queues - questions with delete votes, recently closed etc.?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close)

Workplace has many users who can now vote to delete questions or answers, and a few of them dutifully do so. But finding posts others have voted on is hard; community members have expressed to me they want to help clean up the site, but finding posts in need of more votes is a pain. There's a tab for it in /tools but it's quite hard to find, limited to the last 30 days, and generally a pain in the butt to use.

So what I suggest is simply a Delete/Undelete queue set, which requires the ability to cast delete votes on the site. You'd only see posts you could actually vote to delete (so only show answers with delete votes to people with the Trusted User privilege, not Access to Moderator Tools, as those users can't vote to delete answers).

This was proposed ages ago when we had the old review queue in the long long ago: [Integrate close and delete votes into /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110751/integrate-close-and-delete-votes-into-review) but it was marked as Status Completed without actually adding most of the request into the review process. Now we have close and reopen queues in there, I suggest we have delete/undelete queues in there too.

Having a proper queue, including posts older than 30 days, would allow the community to handle deletions much more easily and quickly, and could allow "Don't delete/Leave Deleted" votes like the Close/Reopen queues allow, to remove items from the queues when they don't require action.